# Binary code for numbers from 2 to 7

Tags: c++

Hello I made simple program for my final school project that codes normal  decadal nuber into binary and vice versa. Problem is with binary part, you see when you input binary code for numbers from 2 to 7 c++ wont recognize them
This is my code (its on Croatian but the text is not important):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
     int n;
cout<<"-------------------------KODER/DEKODER-------------------------"<<endl;
ofstream Info;
Info.open("Info.txt");
Info<<"KODER_DEKODER verzija 1.0.0\nOvaj program je napisan kako bi se brzo dekadni broj pretvorio u binarni i obrnuto bez previse razmisljanja"<<endl;
Info.close();
cout<<"NAPOMENA: Uneseni brojevi i binarne kombinacije moraju biti izmedu brojeva 0 i 15"<<endl;
cout<<"Unesite 1 ako zelite kodirati dekadni broj u binarni, a ako zelite dekodirtai binarni broj u dekadni unesite broj 2"<<endl;
cin>>n;
    int d,b;
    if (n==1){
        cout<<"Unesite dekadni broj koji zelite kodirati u binarni"<<endl;
        cin>>d;
     if (d==0){
    cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 0000"<<endl;
 }else if (d==1){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 0001"<<endl;
     }else if (d==2){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 0010"<<endl;
     }else if (d==3){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 0011"<<endl;
     }else if (d==4){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 0100"<<endl;
     }else if(d==5){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 0101"<<endl;
     }else if (d==6){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 0110"<<endl;
     }else if  (d==7){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 0111"<<endl;
     }else if (d==8){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 1000"<<endl;
     }else if (d==9){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 1001"<<endl;
     }else if(d==10){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 1010"<<endl;
     }else if (d==11){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 1011"<<endl;
     }else if(d==12){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 1100"<<endl;
     }else if(d==13){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 1101"<<endl;
     }else if(d==14){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 1110"<<endl;
     }else if(d==15){
     cout<<"Vas kodirani dekadni broj glasi 1111"<<endl;
     }
     else {
        cout<<"Unesi broj izmedu 0 i 15"<<endl;
        return main();
     }
        }
    else if (n==2) {
        cout<<"Unesite binarni broj koji zelite pretvoriti u dekadni"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
         if (b==0000) {
 cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 0"<<endl;
} else if (b==0001) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 1"<<endl;
} else if (b==0010) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 2"<<endl;
 } else if (b==0011) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 3"<<endl;
 } else if (b==0100) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 4"<<endl;
 } else if (b==0101) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 5"<<endl;
 } else if (b==0110) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 6"<<endl;
 } else if (b==0111) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 7"<<endl;
 } else if (b==1000) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 8"<<endl;
 } else if (b==1001) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 9"<<endl;
 } else if (b==1010) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 10"<<endl;
 } else if (b==1011) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 11"<<endl;
 } else if (b==1100) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 12"<<endl;
 } else if (b==1101) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 13"<<endl;
 } else if (b==1110) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 14"<<endl;
 } else if (b==1111) {
cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 15"<<endl;
 }
 else{
    cout<<" Unesi pravilnu binarnu kombinaciju"<<endl;
    return main();}
    }
        else {
    cout<<"UNESITE 1 ZA KODIRANJE ILI 2 ZA DEKODIRANJE"<<endl;
    return main();}
system("pause");
return 0;}
```

Comment: Hi Mata, welcome to SO. Could you shorten your code for us to see quickly what might be wrong? Here its mind breaking.

Comment: Please take the efforts to translate your code to english, to make it easier for others to answer (remember it's ***you*** coming here looking for help). Also please create a [MCVE] and explain exactly what's going wrong with your code.

Comment: There are much better ways to convert between bases than using endless conditionals and special cases. With this method, when you decide to extend your program to support 32-bit integers, you're going to need over four billion cases for each direction, and the source file will be many, many gigabytes large.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working is because of the leading 0s. `0000` to `0111` are octal (base 8) values. `0010` is 8, `0100` is 64, and so on, which obviously don't match the base 10 values you're reading in.

To get it to work drop the leading 0s (to make them base 10) or do as Gaurav Sehgal suggested and read in a string instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
     cin>>b;
     if (b==0000) {
      cout<<"Vasa binarna kombinacija daje broj 0"<<endl;
      } else if (b==0001) {
      ....
```

You are trying to input a number in binary here and you have declared `b` as `int`.You might want to declare `b` as `string` and then compare `b` with different values like `0000` etc.